# External images not working in SSRS when Report is published only

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2019, ssrs-2019

I already configured: Unattended Execution Account so this is NOT the issue here.

It was also working in the past! SQL Server version is:
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021125) - 15.0.2101.7 (X64)   Jan 23 2023

And this was working before and a few weeks ago it stopped. I have spent 2 full days on this.

I also updated SQL server to latest version to try to resolve this in my dev.

The setting is simple my images work fine in Visual Studio (I use that to create reports) as you can see here:

[image]

Once published here is what it looks like:
[image]
'
Here is the configuration of the image:
[image]

The procedure just returns a clean link to S3 for example:
https://hinkleymedia.s3.amazonaws.com/Product_Images/Website_Processed/3405hb.jpg

Comment: The first thing I would do is test that your server host (the machine running SSRS) can 'see' that URL. It could be security patches etc. that have blocked access and nothing to do with your reports. I assume also that the image it set to scale to fit the image placeholder, if not, and it's cropping the image, you might be seeing the top left corner of that image which is white.

Comment: I will check if the server has access to the images. But yes the image is setup to fit proportional. It works just fine in VS just not on the server!